# How to check mail is sent in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, actionmailer, rspec-rails

**Actionmailer**

```
def welcome_send(user)
        @user = user
        mail to: user.email, subject: 'Welcome to my site', from: 'suhasmv29@gmail.com'
    end
```

**RSpec test case to verify mail has been sent**

```
it "sends a confirmation email" do
      expect { mail.to }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
    end
```

**Error**

```
expected `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### In mailer spec

If it the mailer spec, you can check the from, to and the subject of the email like below.

```
   it 'sends a confirmation email' do
     expect do
       perform_enqueued_jobs do # To perform the job 
         UserMailer.welcome_send(user).deliver_later # Create and send user         
       end
     end.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size }.by(1)
   end
```

#### In controller spec & when the email is set to deliver_now

You can also verify whether the email is sent in the controller spec too.

```
  it 'sends a confirmation email when a new user created' do
    expect do
      post :create, params: {}
    end.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size }.by(1)
  end
```

#### In controller spec & when the email is set to deliver_later

```
it 'should enqueue a mailer job' do
   expect do
     post :create, params: {}
   end.to have_enqueued_job.exactly(:once).and have_enqueued_job(ActionMailer::DeliveryJob)
end
```

Comment: for rails 7, `ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob` instead of `ActionMailer::DeliveryJob`